# How can I rename a file during upload then revert to the original name after upload

Tags: c#, file-upload

I have a requirement to rename files temporarily during upload to an ftp folder but only if the filesize is greater than the chunk size used during the streaming. Since I am using the FileInfo.OpenRead() method is it necessary to do the renaming? The reason is during the upload is it possible for another process to copy part of the file that has been uploaded? If during the copying the file is unavailable for the second process to do the copying then the renaming requirement falls away. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: move the file in the same location with different name. And after you conditions, when you want to rename i again move again to same folder on the same location

Comment: The reason for the renaming is simply to make it not available for the second process. It just so happens that renaming the file to a different file format might make it not possible for the file not to be copied whilst its still in the process of being streamed.What I want is for the file not to be available for the second process if it hasn't finished the streaming process

Comment: Simple rename the file i.e add any prefix or sufix in the name and the start streaming it. May this will help.